# Custom NER model produces bad results after being saved to disk?

Tags: spacy

I've created some training data (about 300 samples) to do NER for recipe ingredients and followed the code example at https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-ner. The newly created model does a decent job when predicting terms on my test dataset, but after saving the model to disk and loading it again, it does not do well at all. I must be missing something about saving the model to disk that loses a lot of accuracy. Is there something I should be doing prior to running the `nlp.to_disk` or some options I need to set?

For example, the new model before saving produced this output:

```
2 pounds tomatillos (about 15 medium), husks removed

Entities:
  2 = QUANTITY
  pounds = UNIT
  tomatillos = INGREDIENT
  (about 15 medium) = COMMENT
  husks removed = COMMENT
```

and after saving and loading (like in the example code):

```
2 pounds tomatillos (about 15 medium), husks removed

Entities:
  2 pounds tomatillos (about 15 medium), husks removed = COMMENT
```

Comment: Looks like others are having similar issues: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3433

Answer (score 0):

Fix should be published shortly. The v2.1 release was pretty big, so we had a couple of regressions like. I thought we already had tests for this as this area of the code has caused problems before, but apparently it slipped through nonetheless.

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3433